# Mysql Bulk insert predefined function not working, SQL Error (1292): Truncated incorrect date value

Tags: mysql

Actual Table

```
assets_tag | purchase_date
---------- | ------
ABCD123    | 11/02/2015 00:00:00
ABCD456    | 29/03/2015 00:00:00
```

Normal select query

`select assets_tag, str_to_date(purchase_date, "%d/%m/%Y" );`

```
assets_tag | purchase_date
---------- | ------
ABCD123    | 2015-02-11
ABCD456    | 2015-03-29
```

if I run it's converted and displayed correctly. but creating a temporary table it's show error **SQL Error (1292): Truncated incorrect date value**

`create TEMPORARY table temp as select assets_tag, str_to_date(purchase_date, "%d/%m/%Y" );`

Thanks

Comment: I think it needs to be `STR_TO_DATE(purchase_date, '%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: str_to_date() function is correct. Bec syntax is str_to_date(string, format).

Comment: I tried, It's how NULL value.

Comment: try this format `STR_TO_DATE(purchase_date, "%d/%m/%Y  %H:%i:%s");`

Comment: Ya, It's run. Thank for your valuable idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
STR_TO_DATE(purchase_date, "%d/%m/%Y  %H:%i:%s");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem of the query is date conversion issue.

`select assets_tag, str_to_date(purchase_date, "%d/%m/%Y" );`
This query is correct for display the output. but you want to insert to another table is throw the error **SQL Error (1292): Truncated incorrect date value**

Slightly change the query format and it's inserted properly. 
`select assets_tag, str_to_date(purchase_date, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s" );`

The actual query is below

`insert into asset_registers ( assets_tag, purchase_date )
select assets_tag, str_to_date(purchase_date, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s" );`

purchase_date - data type is Date.

But I also one doubt how to inserted because the display format is `Y-m-d H:i:s` it's inserted `Y-m-d`.

Thank [Amr Aly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7234275/amr-aly)

Comment: Well explained.